# passing html string to stringbuilder does not work

Tags: c#, html

I am writing html tags in a an html file by following code in C#:

```
StringBuilder sbMarquee = new StringBuilder();
sbMarquee.Append("<a href= #  onclick = showimage('Images\\\\Code00005_0001.jpg')>").Append("<img src=Images\\\\thumbnails\\\\Code00005_0001.jpg></img>").Append("</a>");
_hdCaseMarquee.InnerHtml = sbMarquee.ToString();
```

But, I get following HTML output:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showimage('Images\\Code00005_0001.jpg')"><img src="Images\\thumbnails\\Code00005_0001.jpg"></a></marquee>
```

Following tag from the string is completely ignored:

```
</img>
```

Please Help

Comment: Try by properly quoting, e.g. `Append("<img src=""Images\\\\thumbnails\\\\Code00005_0001.jpg""></img>")`.

Comment: Always check the contents of your variables in a debugger if you get results you don't expect.  If you had, you'd have seen that `sbMarquee.ToString()` had exactly what you were expecting.

Comment: @CodeCaster - `'` and `"` are interchangeable for HTML, to the best of my knowledge, so long as you're consistent for each usage.

Comment: @Bobson but now it says `href= #` and `src={source}` without quotes entirely. Anyway see spender's answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Huh, good point. I'd missed that, since the output looked right for that part of it.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you're looking at the HTML from the browser, in which case there's a strong likelihood that the closing tag of the `img` gets gobbled by the HTML parser for the following reason:

## [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img)

> Tag omission Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag.

Comment: img tags **do not** require a closing tag in html (but the will require it if using xhtml)